# How to compare two next random values from array (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a simple game in Android Studio. I want 5 different images to appear in the center of the screen, every time only one of them. There are two buttons "Yes" and "No". When the next image matches with previous, one's clicking "YES", if not "NO" and after one of the buttons's clicked image changes.

Problems are:
1. I don't know how to compare random values from array images[] and the next one.
2. During testing, I discovered that images are always different. There's no option for getRandom() method to take the same index from array. Probably there's a problem with this method.

For any help, thank you very much :)

Here's the code:

GeomemotryActivity

```
package com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class GeomemotryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button yes_btn, no_btn;
    private ImageView shape;
    private TextView points;

    Integer[] images = {R.drawable.circle,R.drawable.square,R.drawable.star,R.drawable.star6, R.drawable.triangle};
    Random rand = new Random();
    int star6, circle, square, star, triangle, player_points = 0;
    int img, img_prev;

    Integer[] shapesArray = {0,1,2,3,4};

    //int firstShape, secondShape;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geomemotry);
        shape = findViewById(R.id.shape);



        yes_btn = findViewById(R.id.yes_btn);
        no_btn = findViewById(R.id.no_btn);
        points = findViewById(R.id.points);

        points.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        //this line sets random image in the beginning
        shape.setImageResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);

        getShape(); //load shape images


        //there's a problem
        yes_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showShape(shape, getRandom(shapesArray));
                compareShape(img,img_prev);
            }
        });

        no_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showShape(shape, getRandom(shapesArray));
                compareShape(img,img_prev);
            }
        });

    }


    //there's a problem
   private void compareShape(int rnd, int rnd_next)
   {
       rnd = new Random().nextInt(images.length);
       rnd_next = new Random().nextInt(images.length);
       if (rnd_next == rnd)
       {
           player_points+=10;
           points.setText("Points: " + player_points);
       }
       else
       {
           points.setText("Points: " + player_points);
       }
   }

   //probably something's wrong there as well
    private void showShape(ImageView iv, int choice)
    {
        if (shapesArray[choice]==0)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(circle);
        }
        else if (shapesArray[choice]==1)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(square);
        }
        else if (shapesArray[choice]==2)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(star);
        }
        else if (shapesArray[choice]==3)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(star6);
        }
        else if (shapesArray[choice]==4)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(triangle);
        }
    }

    public static int getRandom(Integer[] array) {
        int ch = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
        return array[ch];
    }



    private void getShape()
    {
        star6 = R.drawable.star6;
        circle = R.drawable.circle;
        square = R.drawable.square;
        star = R.drawable.star;
        triangle = R.drawable.triangle;

    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you always rewrite your randoms. In other words, `void compareShape(int rnd, int rnd_next)` in your code is equivalent to `void compareShape() { int rnd; int rnd_next;`

Comment: I agree. I deleted this method because it had no sense. What do you recommend to do to compare these values?